# datagridview auto-select columns disable c#

Tags: c#, collections, datagridview, readonly

I have datagridview to display some data.

I use:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

to select entire column.

When I run application datagridview auto select first column. I am trying to disable it.

If I add:

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

nothing happens.

If I add:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[-1].Selected = true;
```

works great if build in Virtual Studio, but when build to use without Virtual Studio I get error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:index
```

If I click continue it works but the error is annoying.

I tried with:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedColumns.Clear();
```

It works great when build with Virtual Studio, but when build to use without Virtual Studio I get error saying:

```
Collection is read-only.
```

This error is annoying too.

I think best solution would be to set collection to not read-only. But I do not know how to do that.

Any simple solution would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities to get through the `DataGridView`'s auto selection, depending on your case :

On the form's `Load` event :

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

Or on the form's constructor (or everywhere you initialized your `DataGridView`) :

```
SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(
    delegate
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }, null);
```